# Как понять что пароль неправильный

Tags: python, requests, регистрация, пароль

Вопрос краток
Я делаю программу для быстрого входа в аккаунты на различных сайтах используя библиотеку `requests`. У меня вопрос, если пользователь ввёл правильный/не правильный пароль для входа, как программе это понять? При вводе неправильного пароля для входа библиотека `requests` не выдаёт видимой ошибки. Как решить эту проблему без парсинга, или выдаёт ли библиотека ошибку вообще при неправильном вводе пароля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ от запроса будет содержать ошибку под номером 40*. Вместо * будет цифра, которая дает понять, что не так

Например

1. 401 Unauthorized
2. 403 Forbidden
3. 407 Proxy Authentication Required

и так далее. Страничка в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#4xx) со списком ошибок на русском.

в самой программе используйте так

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://anyhosttoauth.com')
print(resp.status_code)
```

Comment: Это будет работать не для всех сайтов. Если разработчик сайта оказался слишком ленивый, то может быть код 200 даже при неверном пароле

Comment: @andreymal не буду утверждать за большинство, но фреймворки бэкенда уже содержат весь необходимый набор для обработки авторизации, и как правило они возвращают нужные коды. Я сейчас за django и за aspnet говорю. Естественно, есть и такое явление, которые вы упоминайте, но это скорей исключение, чем правило

Comment: Django-админка возвращает код 200 при неверном пароле ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal не замечал)) но тут уж больше разговор о drf

Comment: Кстати, это не баг, а фича, потому что [разработчики Django решили, что так логичнее](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24465). Похожая история с [Wordpress](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25446)

Comment: Есть другие способы?

Comment: @Пекарня читайте ответ от сервера если он 200, в теле можно найти описание проблемы